# Setting State with setState() before Render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Yes I know the question has been asked before, but actually doing what is suggested doesn't work for me.

So I have the following method that has to run before I run my render() method (in the parent), because I need to prepare a lot of data for a Google Chart and some CheckBoxes.

As you can see below, this gets called in the function called `parseTestData`:

```
this.setState({
    data: ...,
    levels: ...,
    ...
    ...
    },
});
```

I've omitted quite some information, because I'm not really allowed to share that part. So I call the function `parseTestData` from the parents constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.parseTestData();
}
```

But doing so tells me this:

> Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.

Looking around, the suggestion seems to be to do this instead:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.parseTestData();
}
```

But that doesn't actually set the state at all. All of the children that relies on the parent state now gets undefined props.

What should I do?

Comment: I would suggest you to define and call this this.parseTestData(); in Parent class and do setState there and then pass the state down to child class. Child class I mean currently where you have this.parseTestData()

Comment: This method is called in the parent and whatever comes from that will populate the parents state. The children will then get their props from the parents state. So I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: your testdata seems to be synchronous, so why not set the initial state to it in the constructor with `this.state = { ... }`, for the rest other lifecycle methods you might use is the `componentDidMount`, `static getDerivedStateFromProps`, `componentDidUpdate`, just have a look on the [react lifecycle events](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: @Icepickle because when I use `this.state` (which I did originally) I get a bunch of warnings about not mutating the state directly, but using `setState()` instead. This is for work so I have to try and make that happen as little as possible but maybe it's just unavoidable.

Comment: in the constructor it should be fine, but it really depends on what is your testData, what you are doing with it, and if it will update during the components lifecycle

Comment: @Icepickle the data itself will not change during the components life cycle. Once the parent has the data, the data stays. What data is shown however, does change.

Comment: And from where is this data then coming? Are you only using component state, or other frameworks like redux for state management?

Comment: Another option is to get a `setTimeout(() => this.setState(...`, which basically will defer the setState call and avoid the warning. It does cause another render, but it's only the first time

Comment: Call parseTestData in componentDidMount lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your post i think you are quite new to React.

Basically React checks for any visual changes whenever state changes comparing Virtual DOM it maintains with the DOM and renders it.

If you call your method in the constructor, it will detect visual changes and tries rendering so each time the constructor will be called.

If you are passing props from parent to child make and it is connented to the state of the parent make sure you have a default state.

So coming to your question :

**Parent**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = // set your state but don't ever change state here
    .....
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.parseTestData(); // componentWillMount will also work fine
}

render(){
    return(
        <Child arg={this.state.someArg} />
    )
}
```

**Child**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = // set your state but don't ever change state here
    .....
}

anyFunction(){
    console.log(this.props.arg) // You can access your arguments here 
}
```

Comment: Yes I am very new to React. I've had to learn through trial and error at work as I've never used it before but know JavaScript. So it's been kind of an uphill battle. But thank you for this. I'll try and move forward using this :)

Comment: One more thing, while passing functions to any other component you need to bind the function to the component

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't use this.setState() method inside constructor.Instead of it, you can directly assign a value to the state. Please see below sample code.

```
constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      data:'',
      levels: 2
    }
}
```